# Serializing instants to milliseconds using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson

Using Jackson 2.8.3 and java 8, if I attempt to serialize any `Instant` fields, they seem to get serialized as seconds instead of milliseconds.

This is different from how Jackson serializes `Date`s, which get serialized to milliseconds. But instants get serialized to seconds, with a fractional part.

How can I change this, and have Jackson serialize instants to unix epoch milliseconds as well?

I am doing the following:

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);                 
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS);               
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
```

But it isn't having any effect.

Comment: Do you use the jackson-datatype-jdk8 dependency ? b/c this dependency has the serailizers/deserailizers for Java 8 time classes.

Comment: @Veeram No, but it seems to be deserializing instants fine, however only to seconds. Will that dependency change that to milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, it will, but make sure you only have the write_dates_as_timestamps enabled.

Comment: Don't forget to register the module with object mapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471890/java-instant-is-not-getting-serialized-as-milliseconds-using-jackson)!

I have added the below line in my code.

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Looks like sometimes this line --> `staticMaper.findAndRegisterModules();` does not work as expected.